# Using the SaveAsActivity property with SingleEmailMessage

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a requirement to enable Email tracking for our Salesforce application. The application sends mail using an Html email template and the `SingleEmailMessage` class, setting the latter's `TargetObjectId` property to the `UserId` of recipients. HTML email tracking is enabled for the Account. According to the documentation, it should be possible to use the `SaveAsActivity` property when using this configuration:

> **saveAsActivity** *boolean* Optional. The default value is true, meaning
>   the email is saved as an activity. This argument only applies if the
>   recipient list is based on targetObjectId or targetObjectIds. If HTML
>   email tracking is enabled for the organization, you will be able to
>   track open rates.

However, when the application attempts to send the email with the property set to true, the send fails with status code 121 and the error:

> saveAsActivity must be false when sending mail to users.

This error message appears to directly contradict the documentation. I have seen other comments about the `SaveAsActivity` property on various forums state (without further explanation) that the property must be set to false when sending emails to users.

Please can someone clarify whether or not I should be able to set `SaveAsActivity` to true when sending an email to a user specified in the TargetObjectId property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to this turn out to be to populate the TargetObjectId with ContactIds, not UserIds. The SaveAsActivity property can then be set to true without causing an error.